# Call a POST Action from a selected item in a table (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, post, action

I am new with asp.net mvc4 and dont know how to call a post action from a selected item in a table.

My view model:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public decimal OrdId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resultado de búsqueda")]
    public List<SearchProductModel> products { get; set; }
}
```

Each row of the table is a SearchProducModel's item. When I select one of the list items I want to call action `Add(decimal id)` with route value id = item.id

Comment: any chance you can use a GET?  Then you can simply `@Html.ActionLink("Add Item","Add","Controller", new { id=Model[i].OrdId })` or something similar

Comment: Right now I am using GET, but I want to call directly to POST go over GET.

Comment: I use ajax calls to hit posts on my controller